# Problem in R studio while solving Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP) using Concorde

Tags: r, traveling-salesman, reduction, hamiltonian-cycle, hamiltonian-path

I am working with Concorde to solve TSP problems. Here is my code

```
library(TSP)

concordePath = "E:/Concorde_Code/"
concorde_path(concordePath)
concorde_help()


dataset_path = "E:/RA/"
name = "graph1.txt"
dataset = read.table(paste(dataset_path,name,sep = ""))

arr=dataset
nodelist = unique(as.vector(as.matrix(arr)))
arr_mat = matrix(0,length(nodelist),length(nodelist))
for (i in 1:length(arr[,1])){
  arr_mat[arr[i,1],arr[i,2]] = 1
  arr_mat[arr[i,2],arr[i,1]] = 1
}
arr_mat_new = arr_mat
for(i in 1:length(arr_mat[,1])){
  arr_mat_new[i,which(arr_mat[i,]==0)] = 2 #replace all zero entries with 2
}

d <- as.dist(arr_mat_new)
tsp <- TSP(d)
tsp

o <- solve_TSP(tsp, method="concorde")
labels(o)
```

The Concorde is properly installed on my system and working fine. When I run concorde_help(), I get the following output

```
The following options can be specified in solve_TSP with method "concorde" using clo in control:
/Concorde_Code/concorde
Usage: /Concorde_Code/concorde [-see below-] [dat_file]
   -B    do not branch
   -C #  maximum chunk size in localcuts (default 16)
   -d    use dfs branching instead of bfs
   -D f  edgegen file for initial edge set
   -e f  initial edge file
   -E f  full edge file (must contain initial edge set)
   -f    write optimal tour as edge file (default is tour file)
   -F f  read extra cuts from file
   -g h  be a grunt for boss h
   -h    be a boss for the branching
   -i    just solve the blossom polytope
   -I    just solve the subtour polytope
   -J #  number of tentative branches
   -k #  number of nodes for random problem
   -K h  use cut server h
   -M f  master file
   -m    use multiple passes of cutting loop
   -n s  problem location (just a name or host:name, not a file name)
   -o f  output file name (for optimal tour)
   -P f  cutpool file
   -q    do not cut the root lp
   -r #  use #x# grid for random points, no dups if #<0
   -R f  restart file
   -s #  random seed
   -S f  problem file
   -t f  tour file (in node node node format)
   -u v  initial upperbound
   -U    do not permit branching on subtour inequalities
   -v    verbose (turn on lots of messages)
   -V    just run fast cuts
   -w    just subtours and trivial blossoms
   -x    delete files on completion (sav pul mas)
   -X f  write the last root fractional solution to f
   -y    use simple cutting and branching in DFS
   -z #  dump the #-lowest reduced cost edges to file xxx.rcn
   -N #  norm (must specify if dat file is not a TSPLIB file)
         0=MAX, 1=L1, 2=L2, 3=3D, 4=USER, 5=ATT, 6=GEO, 7=MATRIX,
         8=DSJRAND, 9=CRYSTAL, 10=SPARSE, 11-15=RH-norm 1-5, 16=TOROIDAL
         17=GEOM, 18=JOHNSON
```

This shows that Concorde is installed properly. However, when I try to run the R code (which is given at the top), I get the answer sometimes, while sometimes my program gets stuck. When the program is executed successfully, I get the following output

```
Used control parameters:
clo  =  
exe  =  E:\Concorde_Code\/concorde
precision    =  6
verbose  =  TRUE
keep_files   =  FALSE
/Concorde_Code/concorde -x -o file18ec719b5412.sol file18ec719b5412.dat
Host: Pasha  Current process id: 1165
Using random seed 1586633006
Problem Name: TSP
Generated by write_TSPLIB (R-package TSP)
Problem Type: TSP
Number of Nodes: 66
Explicit Lengths (CC_MATRIXNORM)
Set initial upperbound to 0 (from tour)
  LP Value  1: 0.000000  (0.03 seconds)
New lower bound: 0.000000
WARNING: LK incremental counter was off by 4294967296
Final lower bound 0.000000, upper bound 0.000000
Exact lower bound: 0.000000
DIFF: 0.000000
Final LP has 71 rows, 129 columns, 345 nonzeros
Optimal Solution: 0.00
Number of bbnodes: 1
Total Running Time: 1.70 (seconds)
```

In the above output, the Optimal Solution is 0.00. Can anyone tell me why is this zero? Also sometimes the code does not execute and give the following output

```
Used control parameters:
clo  =  
exe  =  E:\Concorde_Code\/concorde
precision    =  6
verbose  =  TRUE
keep_files   =  FALSE
/Concorde_Code/concorde -x -o file18ec7f123355.sol file18ec7f123355.dat
Host: Pasha  Current process id: 693
Using random seed 1586633314
FATAL ERROR - received signal SIGSEGV (11/11)
Problem Name: TSP
Generated by write_TSPLIB (R-package TSP)
Problem Type: TSP
Number of Nodes: 66
Explicit Lengths (CC_MATRIXNORM)
sleeping 1 more hours to permit debugger access
```

After this output, nothing happens and program seems to go into an infinite loop. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Is that the fault of my system? I am working on core i3 system with Windows 10 and R-studio 64 bit.

Edit: Here is the dataset which I am using

```
   V1 V2
1   1  3
2   1  9
3   1 61
4   2 17
5   2 31
6   2 51
7   3 40
8   3 46
9   4 42
10  4 47
11  4 63
12  5  8
13  5 18
14  5 39
15  6 30
16  6 40
17  6 62
18  7 13
19  7 31
20  7 58
21  8 50
22  8 63
23  9 25
24  9 35
25 10 16
26 10 27
27 10 44
28 11 19
29 11 45
30 11 54
31 12 21
32 12 47
33 12 55
34 13 51
35 13 66
36 14 35
37 14 57
38 14 61
39 15 18
40 15 20
41 15 63
42 16 52
43 16 53
44 17 21
45 17 37
46 18 23
47 19 52
48 19 56
49 20 32
50 20 57
51 21 34
52 22 38
53 22 44
54 22 60
55 23 49
56 23 57
57 24 36
58 24 56
59 24 62
60 25 36
61 25 46
62 26 43
63 26 60
64 26 64
65 27 60
66 27 65
67 28 44
68 28 45
69 28 52
70 29 31
71 29 37
72 29 41
73 30 54
74 30 56
75 32 35
76 32 36
77 33 43
78 33 48
79 33 66
80 34 39
81 34 50
82 37 55
83 38 45
84 38 59
85 39 49
86 40 59
87 41 42
88 41 58
89 42 55
90 43 65
91 46 62
92 47 50
93 48 51
94 48 53
95 49 61
96 53 65
97 54 59
98 58 64
99 64 66
```

Edit 2: Here is the sessioninfo

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] R.utils_2.9.2     R.oo_1.23.0       R.methodsS3_1.8.0 tspmeta_1.2       MASS_7.3-51.1    
[6] ggplot2_3.1.1     TSP_1.1-9        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] modeltools_0.2-22   tidyselect_0.2.5    xfun_0.4            purrr_0.2.5         kernlab_0.9-27     
 [6] lattice_0.20-38     colorspace_1.4-1    stats4_3.5.2        mgcv_1.8-26         yaml_2.2.0         
[11] rlang_0.3.4         pillar_1.4.1        glue_1.3.1          withr_2.1.2         prabclus_2.2-6     
[16] sp_1.3-1            fpc_2.1-11.1        bindrcpp_0.2.2      foreach_1.4.4       bindr_0.1.1        
[21] plyr_1.8.4          robustbase_0.93-3   stringr_1.4.0       munsell_0.5.0       gtable_0.3.0       
[26] mvtnorm_1.0-8       codetools_0.2-15    knitr_1.21          permute_0.9-5       parallel_3.5.2     
[31] flexmix_2.3-14      class_7.3-15        DEoptimR_1.0-8      trimcluster_0.1-2.1 Rcpp_1.0.1         
[36] backports_1.1.4     scales_1.0.0        diptest_0.75-7      checkmate_1.9.0     vegan_2.5-6        
[41] stringi_1.4.3       BBmisc_1.11         dplyr_0.7.8         splancs_2.01-40     grid_3.5.2         
[46] tools_3.5.2         magrittr_1.5        lazyeval_0.2.2      tibble_2.1.3        cluster_2.0.7-1    
[51] crayon_1.3.4        pkgconfig_2.0.2     Matrix_1.2-15       assertthat_0.2.1    rstudioapi_0.8     
[56] iterators_1.0.10    R6_2.4.0            mclust_5.4.2        nlme_3.1-137        nnet_7.3-12        
[61] compiler_3.5.2
```

Comment: Hi Sarwan. Please add a dataset that reproduced your problem. Also, add the output of  sessionInfo() right after you get the error.

Comment: I have added the edgelist dataset in the question. 
Edit: I have included the sessionInfo() detail above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance matrix you create is the problem for Concorde. Concorde should catch that and give an appropriate error message.

Here is an appropriate way to convert a graph represented as an edge list into a distance matrix and solve the TSP (using TSP version 1.1-10 or later):

```
library("igraph")
library("TSP")

# Read edgelist (you can use read.csv or read.table)
edgelist <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 53L, 54L, 58L, 64L), V2 = c(3L, 9L, 
61L, 17L, 31L, 51L, 40L, 46L, 42L, 47L, 63L, 8L, 18L, 39L, 30L, 
40L, 62L, 13L, 31L, 58L, 50L, 63L, 25L, 35L, 16L, 27L, 44L, 19L, 
45L, 54L, 21L, 47L, 55L, 51L, 66L, 35L, 57L, 61L, 18L, 20L, 63L, 
52L, 53L, 21L, 37L, 23L, 52L, 56L, 32L, 57L, 34L, 38L, 44L, 60L, 
49L, 57L, 36L, 56L, 62L, 36L, 46L, 43L, 60L, 64L, 60L, 65L, 44L, 
45L, 52L, 31L, 37L, 41L, 54L, 56L, 35L, 36L, 43L, 48L, 66L, 39L, 
50L, 55L, 45L, 59L, 49L, 59L, 42L, 58L, 55L, 65L, 62L, 50L, 51L, 
53L, 61L, 65L, 59L, 64L, 66L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99"))

# create graph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(edgelist), directed = FALSE)
plot(g)

# convert graph into a distance matrix
d <- as.dist((1/as_adjacency_matrix(g, sparse = FALSE))-1)

# solve TSP
tsp <- TSP(d)

# standard heuristic works, but uses a non-existing edge (path length is Inf)
o <- solve_TSP(tsp)
o
as.integer(o)


# Lin-Kernighan heuristic works, but also uses a non-existing edge (path length is Inf)
o <- solve_TSP(tsp, method="linkern")
o
as.integer(o)

# Concorde finds an optimal solution with path length 0
o <- solve_TSP(tsp, method="Concorde")
o
as.integer(o)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am not getting that error now. However, I have a question.
Can you explain this line 
d <- as.dist(1/(1+as_adjacency_matrix(g, sparse = FALSE)))
if I remove "as.dist", than it run very quickly. Else it is taking very long time. Can you explain why should we use "as.dist"?

Comment: I forgot to put directed = FALSE for creating the graph and I added code that removes Inf for Concorde. Lin-Kernighan does not find a feasible solution. I hope Concord will after you let it run long enough. I use as.dist to create a distance matrix for the symmetric TSP.

Answer (score 0):

So I compiled the code and find out that there is curse of dimensionality issue with the high dimensional adjacency matrix. Here is my final code to cope with this scenario.

Since the distance become meaningless in high dimensions, the as.dist function do not work efficiently for graph with large number of nodes.

Here is my final working code in case anyone wants to check it

```
dataset_path = "E:/RA/Pablo Moscato/dataset/FHCPCS/"
# name = "graph1.txt"  #Found
# name = "graph2.txt" #Found
name = "graph3.txt"
# name = "graph4.txt"
# name = "graph5.txt"
# name = "graph6.txt"  #Found
# name = "graph7.txt"
# name = "graph8.txt"
# name = "graph9.txt"
# name = "graph10.txt"
# name = "graph13.txt"
# name = "graph19.txt"
# name = "graph40.txt"
dataset = read.table(paste(dataset_path,name,sep = ""))
# main_function(dataset)

# create graph
# g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(dataset))
# plot(g)

final_edgelist = dataset

g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(final_edgelist))
# plot(g)

# convert graph into a distance matrix
adj_mat = as_adjacency_matrix(g, sparse = FALSE)
adj_mat_2 = adj_mat

nodelist = unique(as.vector(as.matrix(final_edgelist)))
adj_mat_sym = matrix(0,length(unique(nodelist)),length(unique(nodelist)))
for(i in 1:length(final_edgelist[,1])){
  adj_mat_sym[final_edgelist[i,1],final_edgelist[i,2]] = 1
  adj_mat_sym[final_edgelist[i,2],final_edgelist[i,1]] = 1
}


M = adj_mat_sym
lower_triangle = M[lower.tri(M)]
lower_triangle_2 = lower_triangle
lower_triangle_2[lower_triangle_2==0] = 2
lower_triangle_2[lower_triangle_2==1] = 0
lower_triangle_2[lower_triangle_2==2] = 100



d <- as.dist(1/(1+adj_mat_2))
d_5 = d
d_5[1:length(d_5)] = lower_triangle_2[1:length(lower_triangle_2)]
d_6 <- (1/(1+d_5))

d_7 = d_6
d_7[d_7==1] = 0

# tsp <- TSP(d_6)
tsp <- TSP(d_7)
# tsp_check <- TSP(d)

# o2 <- solve_TSP(tsp)
# o2
# as.integer(o2)


o2 <- solve_TSP(tsp, method="concorde",rep=10, control = list(clo = "-V"))
# o2 <- solve_TSP(tsp_check, method="concorde",rep=10, control = list(clo = "-V"))
o2
as.integer(o2)
```

I hope this clears the doubt if any.